# Prove that $|A| < |A| + |H(A)|$ for all $A$, where $H$ is Hartogs operation.

Tags: set-theory

I was reading Hrbacek and Jech and saw that problem. When we have the Axiom of Choice it is easy, but how can we solve the problem without it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How do you define $<$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that $|A|\leq|A|+|\aleph(A)|$, where $\aleph(A)$ is the Hartogs number of $A$.

Suppose now that there were an injection $f\colon|\aleph(A)|+|A|\to|A|$, then the restriction of $f$ to $|\aleph(A)|$ would be an injection $|\aleph(A)|\to|A|$ and, composing with a bijection $|A|\to A$ and a bijection $\aleph(A)\to|\aleph(A)|$, we would get an injection $\aleph(A)\to A$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, and this way we get that not(|A|>=|A|+|H(A)|), which is not the same as |A|<|A|+|H(A)| without assuming the Axiom of Choice. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterDoe We have both not(|A|>=|A|+|H(A)|) and |A|<=|A|+|H(A)|. |A| and |A|+|H(A)| must be comparable by the latter

Comment: @PeterDoe what does $x<y$ mean, if not $x\leq y$ and $x\neq y$?

Comment: That's exactly what it means.